# How to load prefab from folder only when player want?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a many prefabs in game but I want to load them only when player click button not on start runtime. I know there is only way to load prefabs from Resources folder but it gives me the problem the prefabs are loading all in same time at runtime start not when player click the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the same function on OnClick event.

Click on Button component. there would be an OnClick event.

[image]

Click on +. Drag the gameobject which contains the method and drag that method on OnClickEvent.

[image]

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I know, but to add prefab to scene whene by onclick I need to store that prefab in Resources folder but by that it itself load when game started

Comment: You probably have a code that is loading those prefabs. Probably you need to recheck your Start/Awake function